# I am trying to split this List into blocks

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm

I am trying to make a code that solves Sudoku and I am trying to let the code append each int of the list to another list with the name of the block, like Block1 and Block2. With block I mean the visul seen blocks in the example. But I just do not get it right. The only way that I manage to do it is when I make it with a lot of if statements but there has to be a more efficent way.
Here is the list

```
Sudoku = [0,3,0, 0,0,0, 0,0,0,
          0,0,0, 1,9,5, 0,0,0,
          0,0,8, 0,0,0, 0,6,0,
              
          8,0,0,  0,6,0, 0,0,0,
          4,0,0,  8,0,0, 0,0,1,
          0,0,0,  0,2,0, 0,0,0,
              
          0,6,0,  0,0,0, 2,8,0,
          0,0,0,  4,1,9, 0,0,5,
          0,0,0,  0,0,0, 0,7,0,]
```

And here is my attempt to solve it

```
BlockSpins = 0
Multply = 0
three = 3 
for x in range(len(Sudoku) * 8):
    three *= Multply
    if x >= 0+three and x <=2+three or x >= 9+three and x <=11+three or x >= 18+three and x <=20+three:
        BlockSpins += 1
        if BlockSpins == 9:
            Multply += 1
            BlockSpins = 0
```

Comment: Do you want a 2D list or a 1D list?

Comment: `three = 3 ... three *= Multply` ... That's incredibly confusing. My guy, please use better variable names, like `current_block_position` or something; I'm not quite sure what it represents, but it definitely isn't the number three.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What's your question exactly? Do you want to know a cleaner way to do it? If so, what's the output? This code doesn't output anything or manipulate the board, `Sudoku`. I think you left out a segment. You can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Sidenote: that if-condition would be cleaner without the `and`s: `0+three <= x <= 2+three or ...`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little easier to come up with (and test) a solution if we start with something that's easy to test -- a grid where each value in a block matches the index of that block:

```
sudoku = [
    0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2,
    0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2,
    0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2,

    3,3,3, 4,4,4, 5,5,5,
    3,3,3, 4,4,4, 5,5,5,
    3,3,3, 4,4,4, 5,5,5,

    6,6,6, 7,7,7, 8,8,8,
    6,6,6, 7,7,7, 8,8,8,
    6,6,6, 7,7,7, 8,8,8,
]
```

Our goal is going to be to come up with logic that generates a `blocks` list from a `sudoku` list such that for this test `sudoku` we satisfy the test:

```
assert all(i == v for i, block in enumerate(blocks) for v in block)
```

The way to approach this that makes sense to me is to:

- translate the 1D list to a 2D coordinate system
- group those cells into blocks that are in their own 2D space
- translate the 2D block space into a 1D list of blocks

which is coded as:

```
blocks = [[] for _ in range(9)]

for i, v in enumerate(sudoku):
    x, y = i % 9, i // 9
    b_x, b_y = x // 3, y // 3
    blocks[b_x + b_y * 3].append(v)
```

and this satisfies my test (without any cheating on my part -- the code doesn't use `v` itself to decide how to assign the value to a block), so I'm pretty sure it works correctly.  :)

With your `sudoku` input we get the following blocks:

```
[
    [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
    [8, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0]
]
```